# Can't install redux-logger

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, redux-logger

I'm trying to install redux-logger by following actions:

```
npm install --save redux-logger
```

after that I added import logger to the code:

```
import logger from 'redux-logger'
```

and then I included logger to the applyMiddleware:

```
const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(thunk, logger)(createStore)
const reducer = combineReducers(reducers)
const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducer, undefined, autoRehydrate())
persistStore(store, persistConfig)
```

But I get an error that it's not installed.
Does anybody know why it happens?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

## Installation

Be sure that react-native's packager is shut down. npm/yarn will get stuck or most likely show you an error if you don't shut it down while installing new modules.

## Configuration

If that's your only middleware, you can do as @Amassuo suggested.

```
import  createLogger  from 'redux-logger'
const logger = createLogger();
const store = createStore(
    reducers,
    applyMiddleware(logger)
);
```

Answer (score 3):

i just used createlogger , gave it no options, it works fine, 
this will help you Log and debug, until someone figure it out for us ,

```
import  createLogger  from 'redux-logger'

const logger = createLogger({
    //empty options
});

const store = createStore(
    reducer,
    applyMiddleware(logger)
);
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15620191)

Comment: i thought i was commenting under the first answer, turned out i answerd !
i'm still trying to figure out this problem, maybe i'll edit this to an Answer !

Answer (score 1):

Strangely, i did an

```
npm install 'redux-logger'
```

and got the above error. Curious, i visited the redux-logger npm homepage and noticed the latest version was 3.0.6, but the npm default install pulled down ^2.10.2. I solved this by manually specifying 3.0.6 in my package.json and it fixed the issue after an npm install

Answer (score 0):

Try to import a property logger from redux-logger (not a whole module):

```
import {logger} from 'redux-logger'
```

Comment: In this case I get error "middleware is not a function"

Comment: try to log `thunk` and `logger` variables and look at this usage example: https://github.com/evgenyrodionov/redux-logger#usage

Comment: unfortunately, without success

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem today. Did installation "redux-toolkit", got err.
I just reload Visual Studio Code and the problem is gone.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32642528)